# sharing a url with whatsapp/Facebook

Tags: swift3, whatsapp

I'm trying to share a message string from my app in Whatsapp.  my code for this is below.  my messageString is my message.  If messageString does not include a website link this works with no issue.  However I now need to include a link in what I'm sharing.  Now when I share I just get a blank message in Whatsapp.  I have other share functions in the app such as email/sms which display messageString with a url but my Whatsapp one no longer does.   How can I fix this?

```
let urlStringEncoded = messageString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlUserAllowed)
let url  = URL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(urlStringEncoded!)")


if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {

        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)

    }
}
```

Comment: What you are currently doing is not "sharing" a URL. You are currently trying to open whatsapp with a URL. What do you want to happen here? You should probably be using a `UIActivityViewController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question.   The problem turned out to be the encoding of the URL with included an Equals Sign.  I was unable to send a string containing = with or with out a url.

the problem was fixed by by changing .withAllowedCharacters to

```
 let urlStringEncoded = messageString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics)
```